# Fixed position element that... moves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just found the link with a `visible` element with `position:fixed` behaves kinda strange:

http://www.steadyhealth.com/Do_you_need_to_use_a_back_up_method_for_the_first_week_of_every_month_while_on_birth_control__t267326.html

The element is `div` with `id` equals to `centerMessages`. It appears to be green, visible and ... *moving*. How come that a **fixed** element is *moving* as the page is scrolled? Or, in other words, which part of the spec I need to re-read/re-learn please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div does not move when you scroll. It contains no content, so you can't see it.

Comment: Using firebug and editing the HTML (ie adding some text) confirms exactly what your saying ....

Answer (score 1):

Fixed position just means that the element doesn't move relative to the scroll position of the page; it can still be given a position relative to the browser window. You can change this position using CSS and Javascript.